# How to view custom softkeyboard while tap on EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, keycode, soft-keyboard

I want to show softkeyboard after tapping on EditText in my custom Softkeyboard.

I have made one custom keyboard in which I've added one key.

This key will navigate you to a Conversion View which contains an EditText.
So after tapping on that EditText I want to open my own custom softkeyboard.

Please reply me as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options: create a soft keyboard using the InputMethodService--that is, create a true soft keyboard that will be listed under the keyboard listing in the device's settings that the user can turn on and use at any time. That can be a lot of work.

You're other option is to mock the soft keyboard by creating a custom view, of which you handle input and toggle the visibility of explicitly in your app; blocking the native soft keyboard from showing (which you can do per activity via your manifest or in code).